# Why do my forms break when using an .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

During development, I used subdomain.domain.com and everything worked.
Moving to live, the files are under www, but I wanted to use domain.com, and that's making certain functionalities not work as follows.

I got a dedicated SSL certificate for domain.com, so I have this in my htaccess, and my SSL works fine:

```
# Redirect www.domain.com to domain.com    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However for some reason that breaks some other functionality where a form gets reposted and I can't figure out why.  But if I change htaccess to this:

```
# Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

then the broken functionality works, but the SSL doesn't.

Before I go invest in an SSL for www.domain.com, I wanted to check with the experts here to see if there is something simple I can do to my htaccess file to make both scenarios work.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Might want to try serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

A visible 301 redirect is losing its POST data. From [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2):

> If the 301 status code is received in
>   response to a request other than GET
>   or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT
>   automatically redirect the request
>   unless it can be confirmed by the
>   user, since this might change the
>   conditions under which the request was
>   issued.

So, you have to fix the forms, not the .htaccess.